# Como comparar Select

Tags: sql, select

Tenho uma consulta no Oracle um select com alguns sub selects, tenho que consultar várias tabelas e trazer todos os dados no select principal um única row, tenho dois sub selects da mesma tabela e não posso repetir os dados, tem como comparar dois selects, no caso seria da tbl_contrato_avalista, tenho que trazer os campos de dois avalistas, tem como eu comparar com o sub-select anterior, ou aramazenar o select e comparar. Procurei por recursos do SQL e não consegui uma ideia de como compara selects. O select sem a sub-consulta dos avalistas TBL_CONTRATOS_AVALISTA funciona perfeitamente.
Essa Consulta seria para preencher um dataReader com uma unica row para enviar para o cristal report

```
    SELECT R.NOM_CLIEN
      ,(SELECT COD_CONTEUDO
               FROM TBL_REGISTROS_INDICADORES RI
               WHERE RI.COD_CREDOR = C.COD_CREDOR AND
                     RI.DES_REGIS = C.DES_REGIS AND                               
                     RI.COD_INDICADOR = 'NACIONA') AS NACIONALIDADE
      ,(SELECT COD_CONTEUDO
        FROM TBL_REGISTROS_INDICADORES RI
        WHERE RI.COD_CREDOR = C.COD_CREDOR AND
              RI.DES_REGIS = C.DES_REGIS AND                               
              RI.COD_INDICADOR = 'PROFISSA') AS PROFISSAO                                
      ,R.IND_ESTAD_CIVIL
      ,R.DES_RG
      ,R.DES_CPF
      ,R.DES_ENDER_RESID
      ,R.DES_NUMER_RESID
      ,R.DES_BAIRR_RESID
      ,R.DES_CIDAD_RESID
      ,R.DES_CEP_RESID
      ,R.DES_ESTAD_RESID
      ,(SELECT SUM(VAL_PAGO)                
        FROM TBL_REGISTROS_COMPL_BAIXAS RCB
        WHERE C.DES_REGIS = RCB.DES_REGIS AND
              C.COD_CREDOR = RCB.COD_CREDOR AND
              C.DES_CONTR = RCB.DES_CONTR) AS VALOR_PAGO      
      ,(SELECT SUM(VAL_PRINC)
        FROM  TBL_REGISTROS_COMPLEMENTOS RC
        WHERE C.COD_CREDOR = RC.COD_CREDOR AND
              C.DES_REGIS = RC.DES_REGIS   AND
              --C.DES_CONTR = RC.DES_CONTR AND --VERIFICAR SE PRECISA COMPARAR CONTRATOS
              COD_PRODUT <> '002') AS SALDO_DEVEDOR                        
      ,(SELECT  TCA.NOM_AVALI
               ,TCA.DES_CPF
        FROM TBL_CONTRATOS_AVALISTA TCA 
        WHERE DES_REGIS = '436402114' 
        AND COD_TIPO = 'AVALISTA'
        LIMIT 1)
        ,(SELECT  TCA.NOM_AVALI
               ,TCA.DES_CPF
        FROM TBL_CONTRATOS_AVALISTA TCA 
        WHERE DES_REGIS = '436402114' 
        AND COD_TIPO = 'AVALISTA'
        LIMIT 1)
FROM TBL_REGISTROS_COMPLEMENTOS RC
INNER JOIN TBL_CONTRATOS C 
      ON C.COD_CREDOR = RC.COD_CREDOR AND 
         C.DES_REGIS = RC.DES_REGIS AND
         C.COD_PRODUT = RC.COD_PRODUT AND
         C.DES_CONTR = RC.DES_CONTR                             

INNER JOIN TBL_REGISTROS R
      ON R.DES_REGIS = C.DES_REGIS AND
         R.COD_CREDOR = C.COD_CREDOR

INNER JOIN TBL_REGISTROS_COMPL_BAIXAS RCB2
      ON C.DES_REGIS = RCB2.DES_REGIS AND
         C.COD_CREDOR = RCB2.COD_CREDOR AND
         C.DES_CONTR = RCB2.DES_CONTR 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT CA.COD_CREDOR
                 ,CA.DES_REGIS
                 ,CA.COD_PRODUT
                 ,CA.DES_CONTR
             FROM TBL_CONTRATOS_AVALISTA CA
            WHERE CA.COD_TIPO = 'SOCIO'
           GROUP BY CA.COD_CREDOR
                   ,CA.DES_REGIS
                   ,CA.COD_PRODUT
                   ,CA.DES_CONTR) SOCIO                                                
      ON SOCIO.COD_CREDOR = C.COD_CREDOR AND
         SOCIO.DES_REGIS = C.DES_REGIS AND
         SOCIO.COD_PRODUT = C.COD_PRODUT AND
         SOCIO.DES_CONTR = C.COD_PRODUT                              
WHERE R.DES_REGIS = '436402114' AND R.COD_CREDOR = '1' AND C.COD_PRODUT <> '002'
GROUP BY R.NOM_CLIEN
        ,R.IND_ESTAD_CIVIL
        ,R.DES_RG
        ,R.DES_CPF
        ,R.DES_ENDER_RESID
        ,R.DES_NUMER_RESID
        ,R.DES_BAIRR_RESID
        ,R.DES_CIDAD_RESID
        ,R.DES_CEP_RESID
        ,R.DES_ESTAD_RESID
        ,C.COD_CREDOR      
        ,C.DES_REGIS
        ,R.DES_REGIS
        ,C.DES_CONTR
```

Comment: Comparar de que forma? Porque não passar os subSELECT para um `JOIN`? Neste caso seriam `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Mesmo usando join são dois avalistas, mas pode ocorrer um támbem, tem como eu comparar o Join de cima com o de baixo.

Comment: Como é que sabe se é só um avalista ou mais?

Comment: qual a diferença das duas subselects TBL_CONTRATOS_AVALISTA? elas me parecem identicas.

Comment: Eu não entendi o porque você quer tratar isso no banco, mas tem opção de criar uma function pra isso, se você que guardar as select e comparar as duas, mas acho que se descrever o porque precisa dessa comparação fique mais fácil te dar uma luz. Porque tratar algo assim direto no banco por mais que seja possível vai dificultar a manutenção do código, o certo seria você tratar isso no seu Controller, se eu entendi o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas tratei no código, na tabela avalista tem avalistas de vários contratos, mas geralmente 2 por contrato, e eu precisava preencher um dataReader com os dois avalista e diferentes e tudo em uma única consulta, a solução foi fazer uma consulta separada para os avalista.

Comment: Essa Consulta seria para preencher um dataReader com uma unica row para enviar para o cristal report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi

No oracle acredito que você possa usar UNION para trazer todos os valores de dois selects, INTERSECT para apenas os valores em comum e MINUS para aquilo que está presente em um dos conjuntos menos o o outro conjunto

Dá uma olhada na documentação e veja se ajuda

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm!

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo do tipo:

```
(SELECT  TCA.NOM_AVALI ,TCA.DES_CPF, TCB.NOM_AVALI ,TCB.DES_CPF
        FROM TBL_CONTRATOS_AVALISTA TCA 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  TBL_CONTRATOS_AVALISTA TCB 
        ON (TCA.DES_CPF <> TCB.DES_CPF)
    WHERE TCA.DES_REGIS = '436402114' AND TCB.DES_REGIS = '436402114'
        AND TCA.COD_TIPO = 'AVALISTA' AND TCB.COD_TIPO = 'AVALISTA')
```

Se necessário acrescente um `LIMIT 1`.